# Why are my NSLayoutConstraints not added?

Tags: interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a view with layout constraints that I defined via the Interface Builder. Since they can not be temporarily deactivated, I decided to remove them selectively by just calling:

```c
[view removeConstraint:myConstraint];
```

However, afterwards the constraint still resides inside `view.constraints`. Furthermore, I would then also like to add constraints programmatically (again, because I cannot (de-)activate them):

```c
- (NSLayoutConstraint*) addHeightConstraint:(int)height forView:(UIView*)view {
    NSString* v = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view(==%i)]", height];
    NSArray* cs = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:v options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)];
    NSLayoutConstraint* c = [cs objectAtIndex:0];
    c.priority = 1000;
    BOOL wasAdded = [view.constraints containsObject:c];
    return c;
}
```

Any call of my method results in the value `NO` for the variable `wasAdded`. This is also reflected in the user interface which does not change, at all.

Concluding, I can neither add constraints programmatically nor remove constraints that were added to the storyboard. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not adding the new constraint to the view, therefore, it will not be in the array.

You need to call

```
[view addConstraint:c];
```

Some of the constraints are also kept in `view.superview.constraints`. So if you want to remove the constraints, you could try calling

```
[view.superview removeConstraints:view.constraints];
```

Also, you will need to call (if you did not do it already)

```
[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

If you need to remove the constraints from the storyboard, you could also consider creating your view in code, if you don't have any special setup in the storyboard. Then you would not need to worry about removing and adding constraints.

Let me know if this works for you or you need more help!

Comment: Thank you Catalina. Actually, I found another solution which omits the programmatical removal and addition of constraints (by adjusting the `.constant` values and setting the right priorities). I was not aware of the need to call `addConstraint`, especially since the call of `constraintsWithVisualFormat ` looks as if it already connects the view with the constraint.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy you got to fix your problem. If you have views created in the storyboard, that is the right way to change the constraints, by creating outlets and updating them :) Good luck with your project!

Comment: Good luck to you, too! Fun fact of the day: I am also working in Munich :-). By the way (since I figure this might be relevant for you) you should really leave some contact information in your profile ;-).